# Can you add user roles to IBM Cloud App ID

Tags: ibm-cloud, app-id, ibm-appid

I have an application that uses IBM Cloud App ID for authentication and now we have come the the conclusion that we might need user-role authentication. I have found that there is nothing in the docs explaining if it is possible so I assume it is not but would like some clarification.

Basically just being able to have an account and login is not enough we need to see what type of user that person is so we can restrict some content to admins via IBM Cloud App ID. Have anyone accomplished this? And if so how?

Link to IBM Cloud App ID https://www.ibm.com/cloud/app-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, adding user roles and management is not done with App ID directly, but it can be integrated. App ID is kind of a wrapper around different identity providers such as SAML, Facebook, Google or the built-in Cloud Directory.

There is a [cloud solution tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/serverless-github-traffic-analytics.html) using App ID. The [code for that tutorial is multi-tenant ready](https://github.com/data-henrik/github-traffic-stats) and implements several roles, e.g., admin, tenant admin, viewer, etc.